# Webservice to return auto increment a value in the DB

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

We have a requirement where we will have a field value to be generated automatically. The format of the automatic value should be Currentyear-Dept-001.Depending on the Dept the counter needs to be incrementing like if the dept is English, 2016-English-001 next 2016-English-002 and if the dept is Maths the counter needs to start from first 2016-Maths-001. I am thinking of creating an API which can accept the department name and return the automatically generated values for each Department. If so I will have to create a table in the database, how will have the counter for each department seperately?  Because we dont have the departments  in the database, sometimes the new departments will be coming in. Now not sure how to proceed with this. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Generate the code while saving the data. Instead of getting the code from the server while saving the record. Set a new column with counter to count the Departments

Comment: Your question is essentially a _set of requirements_.   [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with this 2 queries. the first insert a new department or increment the count if it exist. the second read the last count. You also can put the both queries in a stored procedure

```
INSERT INTO myDept (Dept) VALUES ('English')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt = cnt +1;

SELECT Dept, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',Dept,'-',cnt) as Dept_cnt
FROM myDept
WHERE Dept = 'English';
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM myDEpt;
Empty set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO myDept (Dept) VALUES ('English')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt = cnt +1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT Dept, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',Dept,'-',cnt) as Dept_cnt
    -> FROM myDept
    -> WHERE Dept = 'English';
+---------+----------------+
| Dept    | Dept_cnt       |
+---------+----------------+
| English | 2016-English-1 |
+---------+----------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO myDept (Dept) VALUES ('English')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt = cnt +1;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT Dept, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',Dept,'-',cnt) as Dept_cnt
    -> FROM myDept
    -> WHERE Dept = 'English';
+---------+----------------+
| Dept    | Dept_cnt       |
+---------+----------------+
| English | 2016-English-2 |
+---------+----------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM myDEpt;
+---------+------+
| Dept    | cnt  |
+---------+------+
| English |    2 |
+---------+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO myDept (Dept) VALUES ('Math')
    -> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt = cnt +1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT Dept, CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',Dept,'-',cnt) as Dept_cnt
    -> FROM myDept
    -> WHERE Dept = 'Math';
+------+-------------+
| Dept | Dept_cnt    |
+------+-------------+
| Math | 2016-Math-1 |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM myDEpt;
+---------+------+
| Dept    | cnt  |
+---------+------+
| English |    2 |
| Math    |    1 |
+---------+------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```